# How can I have more than one value for my php

Tags: php

Hello how can I input more than one value like on an email $headers on this php function. Here is the code:

```
function strToHex($string){
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    $hex .= "%".dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
return $hex;
}

$script = '<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">Hello world!</p>';

$encoded = strToHex($script);
?>

<script language="javascript">
document.write(unescape("<?php echo $encoded ?>"));
</script>
```

Basically I wanted to have more than one script value for the php function. Here is the code:

```
$script = '<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">Hello world!</p>';
$script = '<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">This is new</p>';
```

How can I add more than one value for my $script?

Comment: function test($val1,$val2,$val3)

Comment: Arrays would be better than multiple fn arguments... more flexible and dynamic.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  Any reason you're having javascript write an encoded string rather than just writing the string directly into the doc?  You're adding a lot of processing on client and server both, with no obvious advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to concatenate it.

Try

```
$script = '<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">Hello world!</p>';
$script .= '<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">This is new</p>';
```

Note the period before the second equal sign.

Comment: Yea that was it...I could not find my email script...How can I add php inside it?

Comment: Can you elaborate more. Putting php inside?